# Disable nf_conntrack

Tags: 12.04

How would I go about disabling the nf_conntrack module in Ubuntu 12.04? I am trying to run an HAProxy on an Ubuntu server, and nf_conntrack is giving me problems when it is running.  I haven't been able to find any documentation on disabling it.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nf_conntrack` is built into the kernel... You cant disable it:

`# lsmod | grep con`

```
nf_conntrack_ipv4      14487  2 
nf_defrag_ipv4         12729  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
nf_conntrack           83275  6 ipt_MASQUERADE,nf_nat,xt_state,nf_nat_ipv4,iptable_nat,nf_conntrack_ipv4
```

`nf_conntrack` is the kernel's modules for handling [network communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter):

`# rmmod nf_conntrack`

```
Error: Module nf_conntrack is in use by: ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat xt_state nf_nat_ipv4 iptable_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4
```

If you need it disabled you can try and disable all the modules that depend on it; but you may find that's not possible. I, for one like a networked system so I'm not even going to try it ;)

Comment: So if I needed to remove the nf_conntrack, the best way would probably be a custom kernel or something of that sort?

Comment: `nf_conntrack` doesn't "handle network communications" :) it's the part of netfilter that trackes connections so that the firewall knows what's happening. nf_conntrack doesn't act on packets like forwarding or dropping them, it just records information about the connections it sees.

Comment: `nf_conntrack` is a kernel module, it's not built into the kernel. The proof is that it's lised in the output of `lsmod`!

Answer (score 5):

1) remove any reference to the state module in iptables. So, no rules like

```
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

the state module requires the nf_conntrack (ip_conntrack) module
```

2) remove the following line (if it exists) in /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config

```
IPTABLES_MODULES="ip_conntrack_netbios_ns"

That module requires ip_conntrack which we are trying to ditch.
```

3) reload iptables without your state rules.

```
sudo iptables -F

# add your real rules
```

4) drop the modules. I had to use:

```
sudo modprobe -r xt_NOTRACK nf_conntrack_netbios_ns nf_conntrack_ipv4 xt_state

sudo modprobe -r nf_conntrack

confirm you don't have a reference to /proc/net/nf_conntrack
```

Answer (score 3):

The answers listed so far are wrong.

First, if it's listed as a module, it's definitely not "built into the kernel"

Creating a file like below will cause it to be forcibly disabled.

```
# cat /etc/modprobe.d/conntrack.conf
install nf_conntrack /bin/false
```

Comment: Wow, this answer is really good. This cuts through all the trouble of disabling other modules and really works. I would say this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

if not use stat module with filter and not use nat table,you can do this to remove the nf_conntrack.

this is test on linux 4.14

```
modprobe -r iptable_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4
```